# Modeling optional filter params in react-apollo

Tags: reactjs, graphql, apollo, react-apollo

I am using [`react-apollo`](https://github.com/apollographql/react-apollo) to access a `graphql` in a web app.

I have a query that looks like this that allows me to filter a schedule of games:

```
query($pagination:Int!, $divisionId:ID, $teamId:ID, $startDate:DateTime!, $endDate:DateTime!
){
 games: allGames (
 orderBy: date_ASC,
 first: $pagination,
 filter: {
   date_gte: $startDate,
   date_lte: $endDate,
   division: {id: $divisionId},
   OR: [
    {homeTeam: {id: $teamId} },
    {awayTeam: {id: $teamId} },
   ]
  }
){
 id
 .... more fields
}
```

The `startDate` and `endDate` variables are required for every request, but the `teamId` and `divisionId` are not. I would like to display all `teamIds` and `divisionIds` in the initial request, and allow the use to filter / drill down as needed.

I was looking to see if I could add a wildcard (`*`) or something of that sort, but I am not sure if it's possible.  With graphql mutations, a `null` value for a variable allows me to write a single mutation that is applicable to multiple use cases (partial updates & creates), but I cannot figure out how to achieve similar functionality with queries.

Do I need to call a different query for each of the filter scenarios (one for no `divisionId` & `teamId`, one for just divisionId, one for just `teamId`, and one for both `divisionId` and `teamId`? Are [fragments](http://dev.apollodata.com/react/fragments.html) something that would help me achieve this with less overhead (because the last sentence makes the process seem a bit too cumbersome / not DRY).

Or do i switch `division` and `id` to `division_in` and `id_in` and pass them (somewhat large) arrays with all the possible values for `divisionIds` and `teamdIds` as initial props?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So it turns out you an actually store the entire filter as a variable (which is pretty awesome).

Here is the updated query:

```
query( $first:Int!, $skip:Int!, $gameFilter:GameFilter! ){
  games: allGames (
    orderBy: date_ASC,
    first: $first,
    skip: $skip,
    filter: $gameFilter
  ){
    id
    ... more fields
   }
}
```

And the corresponding HOC:

```
export default graphql(gamesQuery, {
  options: props => ({
    return { variables: {props.gameFilter}
  });
})(GamesPage);
```

Hat tip to these guys:

- https://www.graph.cool/forum/t/optional-query-filters/355
- https://www.graph.cool/forum/t/is-it-possible-to-build-a-filter-query-dynamically/268